# how to get the auto generated values from sql using c#?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I have an Stored Procedure like below..

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMYSPDetails]    
 @Id VarChar(6),    
 @Name VarChar(50),    
 @Limit Money,    
 @Status VarChar(1),    
 @Accounts As SmallInt    
AS BEGIN    

 IF(LEN(ISNULL(@strDebtorId, '')) = 0) BEGIN    

  WHILE 0 = 0 BEGIN    

   SET @Id = '9' + dbo.fnGenerateRandomCode(5, '0123456789')    

   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytbl WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE s_Id = @Id) BEGIN    

    INSERT INTO Mytbl     
     (D_Id,    
     D_Name,    
     D_Limit,    
     D_Status,    
     D_Accounts,    
     D_dtmStamp,    
     D_Balance)    
    VALUES    
     (@Id,     
     @Name,    
     @Limit,    
     @Status,    
     @Accounts,    
     GETDATE(),    
     @Limit)    

     BREAK   

   END
```

I have c# sharp code to call this SP like this...

```
try
            {
                string Id = "";
                if (hdDId.Value.ToString() != "")
                {
                    Id = hdDId.Value.ToString();
                }

                objDB.blnParamClear();
                objDB.blnParamAdd(ParameterDirection.Input, "@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6, Id.ToString());
                objDB.blnParamAdd(ParameterDirection.Input, "@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, txtName.Value.ToString());
                objDB.blnParamAdd(ParameterDirection.Input, "@Limit", SqlDbType.Money, 8, decimal.Parse(txtLimit.Value.ToString()));
                objDB.blnParamAdd(ParameterDirection.Input, "@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1, cboStatus.Value);
                objDB.blnParamAdd(ParameterDirection.Input, "@intMaxAccounts", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 4, txtAccnts.Value.ToString());

                blnResult = (objDB.lngExecuteSP("spMYSPDetails") == 0);

  }
```

Now I want to catch that auto generated(random)  ID in C# for my reference. I tried but am unable to Catch.. Is there any way to catch the same id that is generated by SP in SQL.Suggest me something...

Comment: "Catch"? Try to use `objDB.blnParamAdd(ParameterDirection.InputOutput, "@Id" ...)`, though your procedure generates ID in a very, very wrong way.

Comment: Please Try this with little implement


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868976/randomly-select-a-row-with-sql-in-access/19873357#19873357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your @ID as output variable.

@Id VarChar(6) output

Then set your C# parameter

SqlParameter paramOutput = new SqlParameter("@Output", SqlDbType.nVarChar);
 paramOutput.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures can have return values and output parameters in addition to input parameters.

Use an **[Output Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**.

Change `ParameterDirection.Input` to `ParameterDirection.Output` when defining a param "@Id".

PS. What are you passing right now to the sproc (`Id.ToString()`) if the id is generated in the DB? Why aren't you just using autoincrement column?