# Randomly Select a Row with SQL in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a small access database with some tables. I am trying the code in the sql design within access. I just want to randomly select a record within a table.

I created a simple table called `StateAbbreviation`. It has two columns: `ID` and `Abbreviation`. `ID` is just an autonumber and `Abbreviation` are different abbreviations for states.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql) thread here. So I tried

```
SELECT Abbreviation
FROM STATEABBREVIATION
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

I get the error Syntax error (missing operator) in query expresion `RAND() LIMIT 1`. So I tired `RANDOM()` instead of `RAND()`. Same error.

None of the others worked either. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: "small access database" ? Please tag your question accordingly

Comment: If you use MS-Access, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937222/how-to-get-random-record-from-ms-access-database

Answer (score 3):

Ypercude provided a link that led me to the right answer below:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ABBREVIATION
FROM STATEABBREVIATION 
ORDER BY RND(ID);
```

Note that for RND(), I believe that it has to be an integer value/variable.

Comment: Note also that is is important to provide the integer primary key value as an argument (`RND(ID)`) so that Access SQL will generate a different random value for each record. (If you simply use `ORDER BY RND()` then the query optimizer considers the function call to be deterministic and only evaluates it once. Therefore you get the same "random" value for all rows.)

Answer (score 2):

You need both a *variable* and a *time seed* to not get the same sequence(s) each time you open Access and run the query - and to use *Access SQL* in Access:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Abbreviation
FROM STATEABBREVIATION
ORDER BY Rnd(-Timer()*[ID]);
```

where ID is the primary key of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it is helpful to you

It is possible by using a stored procedure and function, which I created it's have a extra column which you could be create in your table FLAG name and column all field value should be 0 Then it works

```
create Procedure proc_randomprimarykeynumber
as
    declare @Primarykeyid int  

    select top 1  
        @Primarykeyid = u.ID 
    from 
        StateAbbreviation u  
    left join  
        StateAbbreviation v on u.ID = v.ID + 1 
    where 
        v.flag = 1 

    if(@Primarykeyid is null )
    begin
        UPDATE StateAbbreviation 
        SET flag = 0  

        UPDATE StateAbbreviation 
        SET flag = 1 
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
                     FROM dbo.StateAbbreviation)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE StateAbbreviation 
        SET flag = 0 

        UPDATE StateAbbreviation 
        SET flag = 1 
        WHERE ID IN (@Primarykeyid)
    END 

    SET @Primarykeyid = 1 

    SELECT TOP 1 
        ID, Abbreviation 
    FROM
        StateAbbreviation 
    WHERE
        flag = 1
```

It is made in stored procedure run this and get serial wise primary key

```
exec proc_randomprimarykeynumber
```

Thanks and regard

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM tbl_name
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Of course this may have performance considerations for large tables.

Comment: It will have "performance considerations" under Access SQL in every case, specifically "Undefined function 'NEWID' in expression."

Comment: Oops - I didn't notice the word "Access" in the OP - I just assumed SQL Server.